# Set select element width equal to it's option's content width dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, dom

Im trying to make select element width equal to it's option text width in angular.

My HTML component simply look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  ...
  <select (change)="adjustSelectWidth($event.target)" formControlName="members">
    <option value="1">Me</option>
    <option value="2">Me, my spouse</option>
    <option value="3">Me, my spouse and my kids</option>
  </select>
  ...
</form>
```

What I have tried:

- Get the option element width using `clientWidth` then apply that to select element but that width is 0.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    members : new FormControl(''),
  })

  adjustSelectWidth(e){
    const optionValue = this.profileForm.get('members').value;
    const optionWidth = document.querySelector(`option[value="${optionValue}"]`).clientWidth;
    e.style.width= optionWidth + "px"
  }
}
```

- Get the option's `innerHTML` length then mutiply it with a fixed pixel but it not a dynamic option

```
export class AppComponent  {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    members : new FormControl(''),
  })

  adjustSelectWidth(e){
    const optionValue = this.profileForm.get('members').value;
    const optionTextLength = document.querySelector(`option[value="${optionValue}"]`).innerHTML.length;
    e.style.width= optionTextLength*8 + "px";
  }
}
```

- Append the options's `innerHTML` to a span element for measuring width, but then that span `clientWidth` does not accurate when I apply it's to the select element

```
export class AppComponent  {
  //This temp is bind to a span via string interpolation {{...}}
  temp:string;

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    members : new FormControl(''),
  })

  adjustSelectWidth(e){
    const optionValue = this.profileForm.get('members').value;
    const optionText = document.querySelector(`option[value="${optionValue}"]`).innerHTML;
    this.temp = optionText;
    const spanWidth = document.querySelector(`.temp`).clientWidth;
    e.style.width = spanWidth + "px";
  }
}
```

Since im using angular, i prefer not to use JQuery. Additionally, why the `clientWidth` seem to not solve my problem here

I created a stackbliz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbimkz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to measure text width. I think it is sufficiently reliable, but might be a bit expensive in terms of performance, depending on your app of course. (The simplistic example in Stackblitz has no performance problem.)

The method is to actually append a hidden element to the document containing the text you want to measure, read the `clientWidth`, and remove the element immediately.

Modify `adjustSelectWidth()` as follows:

```
adjustSelectWidth(e: HTMLSelectElement){
  // assuming something is always selected, please test!
  const displayedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerText;
  const dummy = document.createElement('div');
  dummy.innerText = displayedText;
  dummy.style.position = 'absolute';
  dummy.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.insertBefore(dummy, document.body.firstChild);
  const measuredWidth = dummy.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
  e.style.width = (measuredWidth + 30) + 'px'
}
```

Modified Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpjxbd?file=src/app/app.component.ts - tested in latest Firefox, Chrome, Edge

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but the select width seem to have an addition width at the end that scale up depend on the length of the text which not equal to 30px you added to it. Can you share how that behavior happened ?

Comment: Oh I figured it out, it because of the font-size of the span is bigger than the font-size of the select-element

Comment: Thank you very much. Additionally, I think you can add `document.body.removeChild(dummy);` before setting width for `dummy` removal

Comment: Ho! I was cleaning up the code and removed the `removeChilde(dummy)` call! Thanks for noticing, will amend the answer+Stackblitz!